# Randomly choose one method? attribute error - Python

Tags: python, list, methods, attributes, instapy

Using instapy, I am using both a following and unfollowing method. In an attempt to halve the time needed for the program to run, I'm trying to have the program only follow or unfollow each time I run it. Instead of having to manually comment out one method or the other, I tried put both in a list, and use random.choice() to pick one or the other to run.

```
account_list = ['dji_official' , 'drone', 'dronenerds', 'dronepals']
first = session.follow_likers([random.sample(account_list, 2)], photos_grab_amount = 2, follow_likers_per_photo = 15, randomize=True, sleep_delay=25, interact=False)
# unfollow
second = session.unfollow_users(amount=40, allFollowing=True, style="FIFO", unfollow_after=12*60*60, sleep_delay=15)

action_list = [first, second]
random.choice(action_list)
```

This code returned an error "'list' object has no attribute 'replace'"
Not sure where/why it is throwing this error. Is there an easy fix? or would I be better off trying a function(s)?

Comment: The line `random.choice(action_list)` literally has no effect, is that really what you're doing in your actual code?

Comment: yes I'm pretty new to coding. the session.follow_likers method works by itself, so I figured if I stored it in a list, and then used random.choice to pull it back out of the list, that it would run as it did before. I tried both storing it in the list as a variable "first" and storing itself in the list, both returned the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a great use for an `if`.  You could structure your code like this:

```
account_list = ['dji_official' , 'drone', 'dronenerds', 'dronepals']
action_list = [1, 2]
option = random.choice(action_list)
if option == 1:
    session.follow_likers([random.sample(account_list, 2)], photos_grab_amount = 2, follow_likers_per_photo = 15, randomize=True, sleep_delay=25, interact=False)
elif option == 2:
    session.unfollow_users(amount=40, allFollowing=True, style="FIFO", unfollow_after=12*60*60, sleep_delay=15)
```

Notice that, as was pointed out above, you need to store the result of running `random.choice` in a variable (I called it `option`) so you can do something with it, like check it in an `if`.